# Could not find spring-boot-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am running into the following error when i try to build my spring boot project in gradle. I got the build.gradle from the spring initilizer.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:20200409.145011-519).
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.3.0.BUILD-20200409.145011-519.jar

Please find my gradle build

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.mycompany'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' //TODO how does verioning work in this project?
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation ('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'){
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation ('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'){
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a special reason to use specifically the `SNAPSHOT` version I suggest using *release* or *milestone*.

SNAPSHOT builds are quite unstable. If you want to take a look at the new 2.3 version of the Spring Boot you should probably use the milestone version. For today it would be `2.3.0.M4`.

For that, change `org.springframework.boot` plugin version like this:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.M4'
```

Comment: The probable reason for the problem is that the name should be the same for `jar` and `pom` artefacts of the build, however at https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/ I see that `jar` timestamp is different from other build artefacts of the 519 build. Probably this should not have happened. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDszc.png